# Excluding reads from members in the same organization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm newbie in Firebase and I'm not sure how to accomplish the following or even if it's possible at all.

I want to model two entities under a restriction explained later:

1. **Students** - can produce a piece of work that needs to be evaluated by reviewers
2. **Reviewers** - can review as many pieces of work done by students

Both **students** and **reviewers** belong to **schools** and I need to **restrain** reviewers from receiving **works done by students that belong to their same school**.

I know I could filter this in the front-end but I need to be sure that this is filtered by Firebase and leakage of data would be possible by sending requests with Postman/curl directly to Firebase.

In other words, reviewers can fetch all piece of works except those done by students that belong to their same organization.

Do you know how to model this in Firebase rules or a workaround on it that will work exclusively on the back-end?

Comment: Without specific data (you datastructure and such) this question is very hard to answer. But I think you are looking for [query based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query_based_rules). With that you can specify in your rules a reviewer can read when work != from same school. Just make sure your security rules and read code are a match with query based rules.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks